# how to use std::function<void(void)> to call a method

Tags: c++

I am trying to use an method that takes

```
  std::function<void()>
```

as an input. Unfortunately I have never used this data type before and I am having problems understanding it. All I need to do it say when it is called execute a method, for example:

```
   std::function<void()> doThing = object.isMethod();
```

Although this syntax is obviously not correct. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: You can't say "execute a method", you have to say "execute a method _on this object_". Mike's answer shows how to capture a pointer or reference to `object` so that the method is invoked on _that object_.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the object to the method

```
std::function<void()> doThing = std::bind(&type::isMethod, &object);
```

or use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
std::function<void()> doThing = [&]{object.isMethod();};
```

Comment: With all the respect to the elegant answer in time(2014), for those who are into latest c++ (c++20 or later) , its recommended  reduce the use of bind. Just an additional info.